# How to define seperated indexes for different logs in Filebeat/ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am wondering how to create separated indexes for different logs fetched into `logstash` (which were later passed onto `elasticsearch`), so that in `kibana`, I can define two indexes for them and discover them.

In my case, I have a few client servers (each of which is installed with `filebeat`) and a centralized log server (`ELK`). Each client server has different kinds of logs, e.g. `redis.log`, `python` logs, `mongodb` logs, that I like to sort them into different indexes and stored in `elasticsearch`.

Each client server also serves different purposes, e.g. databases, UIs, applications. Hence I also like to give them different index names (by changing output index in `filebeat.yml`?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Filebeat configuration you can use [`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_document_type) to identify the different logs that you have. Then inside of Logstash you can set the value of the `type` field to control the destination index.

However before you separate your logs into different indices you should consider leaving them in a single index and using either `type` or some [custom field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) to distinguish between log types. See [index vs type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type).

Example Filebeat prospector config:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - paths:
        - /var/log/redis/*.log
      document_type: redis

    - paths:
        - /var/log/python/*.log
      document_type: python

    - paths:
        - /var/log/mongodb/*.log
      document_type: mongodb
```

Example Logstash config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  # Customize elasticsearch output for Filebeat.
  if [@metadata][beat] == "filebeat" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      manage_template => false
      # Use the Filebeat document_type value for the Elasticsearch index name.
      index => "%{[@metadata][type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      document_type => "log"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `document_type` in filebeat will create a `[@metadata][type]` field in the logstash event and not a `[type]` field? I think it should read `index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` instead.

Comment: The `document_type` value is used for both the `[@metadata][type]` and `[type]`, so either field can be used for the index.

Comment: document_type is not working in es6+, but works well wihth es4, es5..I guess that's my problem..

Answer (score 2):

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log
    paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
  fields: {log_type: toolsmessage}


- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_access_*
  fields: {log_type: toolsaccess}
```

in the logstash.conf.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5043"
  }
}

filter {
  if ([fields][log_type] == "toolsmessage") {
    mutate {
      replace => {
        "[type]" => "toolsmessage"
      }
    }
  }
  else if ([fields][log_type] == "toolsaccess") {
    mutate {
      replace => {
        "[type]" => "toolsaccess"
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["10.111.119.211:9200"]
    index => "%{type}_index"
  }
 #stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiple-filebeat-inputs-with-logstash-output/146343/4 may works too, but I havn't test this..

Answer (score 1):

In logstash you can define multiple input, filter or output plugins with the help of tags:

```
input {
    file {
            type => "redis"
            path => "/home/redis/log"
    }
    file {
            type => "python"
            path => "/home/python/log"
    }
} 
filter {
    if [type] == "redis" {
            # processing .......
    }
    if [type] == "python" {
            # processing .......
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "redis" {
            # output to elasticsearch redis
            index => "redis" 
    }
    if [type] == "python" {
            # output to elasticsearch python
            index => "python"
    }
}
```

Comment: this works actually ,but I guess the https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-multiple-different-file-beat-logs-in-logstash/76847 contails more details

Answer (score 0):

I have read all of the above.
Finds out my way.

```
input {
    stdin {
    }
    jdbc {
      type => "jdbc"
      ....
    }
    http_poller {
        type=>"api"
      ....
    }

}
filter {
....
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["jlkjkljljkljk"]
        index => "%{type}_index"
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => json_lines
    }
}
```